# Linux Server deployed JSP - Http 404 the requested resouce is not available

Tags: linux, jsp, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am working on a web based project in eclipse on a system with jre 1.8 and Tomcat 8.

My application works fine on my system.

Now I have to deploy my application on a linux server machine.. As I am a novice I am facing some difficulties.

My server machine has Tomcat 7 installed.

For deployment , i was copying the sources from wtpwebapps from my system to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` on my server machine.

But now only html webpages are showing up and all the jsp files are giving the `HTTP: 404 The requested resource is not available`.

My Folder Structure is M`yProject/WebContent/(DisplayResults.jsp & Homepage.html)` & servlet is located at `MyProject/src/Utility/Servlet.java`

Homepage.html

```
<form method="get" action="/MyProject/Servlet">
   <input type='text' name='q' value='Type your text'><br>
   <br> <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Servlet.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String query = request.getParameter("q");
    System.out.println("query is " + query);

    request.setAttribute("itemList", list);
    request.setAttribute("q", query);

    RequestDispatcher view = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/DisplayResults.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
}
```

DisplayResults.jsp

```
    <%@page import="Utility.*"%>
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#fdf5e6">

        <table>
            <td><c:forEach var="d" items="${itemList}">
                    <b><a href='<c:out value="${d.itemLink}"/>'>${d.itemTitle}</a></b>
                    <br>
                    <small>${d.itemLink}</small>
                    <p>${d.itemDesc}</p>
                </c:forEach></td>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

On server machine, the html file opens up but for jsp file it gives resource not available error.

I have read across through several related posts, I could not find the exact scenario being answered.I guess the issue is related to the class files for the jsp not being found. As I am copying the wtpwebapps folder manually , i think something is getting missed.

Kindly please help.
    Also I would like to know where can I check errors on the server machine.

Comment: add your Web.xml as well as the URL youa re suing to access the JSP.

Comment: Also I think you are copying the source instead of build. follow the instructio in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using eclipse you can create War file and deploy the same to your server machine's tomcat/webapps folder. Restart your Tomcat server and let tomcat auto load your application.

`yourProject(Right Click)->export->web->war`

There select your project, Provide name of the war file to be generated.
**Note**: Your application context will be same as your War file name.
In this way you can avoid any mistakes happening due to direct file transfer.

Another thing I noticed is that you are using your action url as `/MyProject/Servlet`.
Try using this in your form action `Servlet`.

Your form tag will become

```
<form method="get" action="Servlet">
```

Comment: thanks.. Also i realized I was facing issue because the linux server had tomcat7 and i was trying to execute jre1.8 code over it, which i realized are incompatible.. My problem solved on server with tomcat8, jre1.8 and war deployment as specified by you..

Comment: I could never have thought of this. It would be helpful to help if you had  mentioned your complete environment before hand.